# Change height of UIImageview dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageview inside a UITableViewCell whose height need to change depending on the scale of image so I did

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500.0  //arbitrary value
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //change height of UIImageView
    let image_width = homeViewCell.mainImageView.frame.size.width
    let image_height = image_width * CGFloat(viewModel.imageScale)
    homeViewCell.mainImageView.frame.size.height = image_width * CGFloat(viewModel.imageScale)
    //load image
    _ = homeViewCell.mainImageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: serverURL + viewModel.mainImage)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named : "home_placeholder") ...
}
```

In storyboard i have set the height constraint of imageview as fixed number and content mode as "Scale to fill"

This is not resizing the UIImageView based on the scale of image.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to update the image view's `frame` if you're using auto-layout constraints. Get a reference to the height constraint and use `heightConstraint.constant = image_height` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using auto-layout constraints you need to update height constraint not image view frame. So connect your height constraint as an `IBOutlet` `heightConstraint` in your tableViewCell. And then in table view `cellForRowAt` you have to set `cell.heightConstraint.constant = image_height`. And this will give you the desired result.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // don't forget to dequeue your table view cell here
   //change height of UIImageView
   let image_height = image_width * CGFloat(viewModel.imageScale)
   cell.heightConstraint.constant = image_height
   //load image
   _ = homeViewCell.mainImageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: serverURL + viewModel.mainImage)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named : "home_placeholder") ...
}
```